# Ant build script/eclipse won't compile with deprecated Jars

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, build, jodconverter

I've downloaded this library called JODConverter thats been discontinued, https://code.google.com/p/jodconverter/ and I'm trying to include it in my Java Project in Eclipse. I've right clicked on the project and added the required jars to the build path and I've run a stand alone class to test the library and it works fine. Currently I'm trying to run some code from these jars in my project. I use a custom build script written in ant and I'm getting the following output for the classes I'm trying to use:

```
error: package org.artofsolving.jodconverter does not exist
    [javac] import org.artofsolving.jodconverter.OfficeDocumentConverter;

error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]          OfficeManager officeManager = new DefaultOfficeManagerConfiguration().setTaskExecutionTimeout(300000L).buildOfficeManager();

[javac]   symbol:   class OfficeManager
    [javac]   location: class XLSXConverter

 [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 14 errors
```

I'm still kind of a beginner with ant/including jars and I'm not really sure how to get around the deprecation if that's even the problem here. Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated